# SQL ORDER BY multiple fields with sub orders

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, dbal

I'm trying to make a query to get the list of a students class ordered by the type defined, sex and name.

I have the next query:

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENTS
  ORDER BY FIELD(type, 'b', 'p', 'j', 'i', 'a', 'c', 'v'), FIELD(sex, 'M', 'F'), `name` ASC
```

I'm getting that order, first type, and then both sex from that type and name, but I need to define some types and sex together, something like this:

```
type = 'b', sex = 'M', name
type = 'b', sex = 'F', name
type = 'p', sex = 'M', name
type = 'p', sex = 'F', name
type = 'i', sex = 'M', name
type = 'a', sex = 'M', name
type = 'c', sex = 'M', name
type = 'v', sex = 'M', name
type = 'j', sex = 'M', name
type = 'i', sex = 'F', name
type = 'a', sex = 'F', name
type = 'c', sex = 'F', name
type = 'v', sex = 'F', name
type = 'j', sex = 'F', name
```

Comment: What is sex `H` ?

Comment: is there a column with type and sex ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza just a mistake, it's 'F'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a `CASE` statement to create the expression you want

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/275094/3)**

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN type = 'b' and sex = 'M' THEN 1
              WHEN type = 'b' and sex = 'F' THEN 2
              WHEN type = 'p' and sex = 'M' THEN 3
              WHEN type = 'p' and sex = 'F' THEN 4
              ....
              ELSE 9999
          END,
          name
```

Comment: This case is ordering by name, doesn't care about type or sex.

Comment: Nope, this case order first for `{type, sex}`  combinatation and then for `name`, did you try it?

Comment: Yep, and didn't work. It orders just by name and doesn't care about type neither sex.

Comment: Because you didnt fill all the cases. That was the intent for `...` and if didnt match any `CASE` by default return `NULL` and nulls go first.  But you can solve it by adding the `ELSE` condition.